# Generating lines from coordinate file using R?

Tags: r, sp, sf

I have got an excel sheet with X and Y coordinates, actually Y is constant, since it is a straight line. I want a Shapefile with as many features as distance between points. I only get one line from the whole transect by using Linestring, but I need every segment, I tried with Multilinestring, but sincerely, I'm completely a beginner and after 2 days trying I couldn't get it.

```
library(sf)

x<- c(P$x)
y<- c(P$y)
coord2<- cbind(x,y)
print(coord2)
head(coord2)
L1<- st_linestring(coord2)
plot(L1, axes = TRUE)
class(L1)
geometria7 <- st_sfc(L1)
plot(geometria7, axes = TRUE)
st_write(geometria7, "proof.shp")
```

[image: raw dat]

Comment: So just to be clear for your sample 9 points you want to get 9x8/2 = 36 line segments?

Comment: the values are the length of the canopy of each specie, in 15 transects of 50 meters each, so, it could be thousands segments, I need all of them features in one Shapefile.

Comment: what "values"? I don't see any values, only points. You've shown us 9 data points, and if that was *all* your data, would you expect to get 36 line segments?

Answer (score 2):

First make some random points for testing - its probably hard to tell whats going in with points in a straight line, so I'll make some random points:

```
pts = cbind(runif(6),runif(6))
```

next work out which points we need to combine to generate (in this case) the 6x5/2 = 15 features using the handy `combn` function:

```
> combo = combn(nrow(pts),2)
> combo
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12] [,13] [,14]
[1,]    1    1    1    1    1    2    2    2    2     3     3     3     4     4
[2,]    2    3    4    5    6    3    4    5    6     4     5     6     5     6
     [,15]
[1,]     5
[2,]     6
```

next we iterate over the columns of that matrix, taking corresponding rows from the points, and making an `st_linestring` object - the `lapply` gives us a list which we turn into a simple features column:

```
slines = do.call(
  st_sfc,
  lapply(
     1:ncol(combo),
      function(i){
         st_linestring(
           rbind(
              pts[combo[1,i],],
              pts[combo[2,i],]
           )
         )
       })
    )
```

So we should see six points, each with five connecting lines:

```
> plot(slines)
> points(pts,pch=19,col="red")
```

and make a shapefile:

```
> st_write(slines, "/tmp/foobar.shp")
Writing layer `foobar' to data source `/tmp/foobar.shp' using driver `ESRI Shapefile'
features:       15
fields:         0
geometry type:  Line String
```

Comment: Super interesting. but unfortunately this creates too many combinations following this method. As I have already achieved the points and a single line, therefore I have been able to use ArcMap tool "split line at point". it would be possible to do it with an R sprip?

Comment: So if your complete data set is 9 points, you want 8 features, each one a line segment connecting point N with point N+1?

Comment: yes, exactly that. Actually my complete data set is 56 points, I would need 55 line features. Thanks!!!

Comment: ah, you said "as many features as distance between points", and between N points there are N*(N-1)/2 distances, so I though you wanted lines between every pair of points. I'll redo.

Comment: no, it's not exactly like that. What I did in my field work was to write down the length of each specie in a 50 meters straight transect. I also have the length of each segment (could be better or the coordinates?. So I need to transform this data to Shapefile, and then,put it on a multispectral image. I mean if I wrote down 100 specie lengths, I'll will have 100 lengths or 101 points. Thank you very much :)